# How would I turn an object into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to turn an object that I have into and array of objects, I know there must be a simple way of doing this but I cannot seem to figure it out after searching. I'm probably searching the wrong thing.

I've tried pushing to an array but I need each key and value pair to be a separate object in an array.

This is the object that I'm working with:

```
{ HI: 1,
  undefined: 7,
  MI: 1,
  FL: 1,
  WV: 1,
  TX: 1,
  IA: 3,
  MN: 1,
  MO: 1 }
```

Not quite sure how to turn each of those values into an object, yes I'm stupid.

the desired output would be `[{stateName:'HI' value: 1},{stateName: 'Mi', value: 4},{stateName: 'TX', value: 1}]` and so on.

Comment: Can you show us your current attempt and an example of the desired output?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I added the desired output to the question at the bottom so you can see what I'm meaning.

Comment: Why would you want an array of objects when each object has different properties?

Comment: @Chameleon That's half the requirements, but we'll also need to see your code so we can help you fix it :) Per the rules: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.*

Comment: It might be useful if you wanted something like `[{state: 'HI', value: 1}, {state: 'IA', value: 3}, ...]`

Comment: Are you aware of the `Object.entries` method?

Comment: @Barmar There are plenty of use cases for an array of key-value pairs as opposed to an object. For example, any situation where order is important.

Comment: @Barmar that is exactly what I want actually.

Comment: I've edited it to explain what I want, I screwed up my first edit.

Comment: `Object.entries(input).map(([ stateName, value ]) => ({ stateName, value }))`

Comment: @user633183 this works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`var array = [];`

```
var yourObj = {...}

Object.keys(yourObj).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = {[key]:obj[key]};
   array.push(obj)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
let obj = { HI: 1, undefined: 7, MI: 1,FL: 1,WV: 1,TX: 1,IA: 3,MN: 1,MO: 1 };
let list = [];
for (let name in obj) {
    let item = {};
    item[name] = obj[name];
    list.push(item);
}
```